# Random launch screen on iOS apps

Tags: ios, random, screen, launch

Is it possible to make an random launching image in iOS? Well, the thing is that launching screen is obligated and it should be an first screen of the application, but in my application the background changes every time when it's display.

Comment: If you're talking about a random launch image when starting Xcode.app, I wouldn't advise hacking the .app. If you're talking about a random launch image for an OS X application that you have written, then yes, it is possible. If, rather, you are talking about a random launch image for an iOS application, no I do not think this is possible.

Which are you asking about?

Comment: I am asking about IOS app unfortunetly.... so does it mean i will have to resign random background image on the first screen of my app?